# AngularJS ui-grid: how to select the the set of attributes in a Data to display in tabe

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to use the ui-grid for displaying the data from ajax call. 
the data returning from the call have many attributes. But i need to display the particular attributes in a ui-grid. How to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example ajax call return below attributes

```
  var resp = {
"Status":true,
"Msg":"",
"SendTran":[{
"Document_Gid":"XXXX",
"DocumentId":"XXX",
"DocumentType_Name": "XXX",
"Created_Date":"XXXX",
"Verification_Status":"XXX"
}]
};
```

resp is ajax return values. this have multiple attributes and we need only **SendTran** attributes to bind the grid.

```
var data = [];
$scope.sendtranscripts = {
        paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 75],
        paginationPageSize: 20,
        showGridFooter: true,
        showColumnFooter: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: false,
        selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,

        columnDefs: [         
            {
                field: 'DocumentId', width: '20%', displayName: 'Document ID', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true
            },
            {
                field: 'DocumentType_Name', width: '40%', displayName: 'Document Name'
            },
            {
                field: 'Verification_Status', width: '20%', displayName: 'Document Status'
            },
            {
                field: 'Created_Date', width: '20%', displayName: 'Created Date'
            }

        ],
        data: data
};
$scope.sendtranscripts.data = resp.data.SendTran;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. I'm loading the some columns dynamically and , and but the data for those dynamic column  is coming in ajax as an object which in turn as an array of objects. for example :
dataObject{
attribute1;' ',
dynamicColumnDataArray:[
{
attribute2:' ', 
},{},{}
]
}
if i want to access attribute2, how can i access that ?